# Unable to display returned value from php called by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is the function.:
Where i try to call available.php and it returns an html .
I try to append that returned result on the check label. 
I am getting the image but not able to see the result text.

```
  <span class="check"  ></span> <br/>
<p> </p>


$("button").click(function () {
    $('.check').show();
    $('.check').fadeIn(400).html('<img src="image/ajax-loader.gif" /> ');

    var pincode = $("#pincode").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "available.php",
        data: {
            'pincode': pincode
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            var result = result;
            if (result == '') {
                $('.check').html('<img src="image/error.png" /> This pincode is not          valid');

                $('.check').append(result);

                $(".check").removeClass("red");
                $('.check').addClass("green");
                $(".pincode").removeClass("yellow");
                $(".pincode").addClass("white");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Php code:

```
  <?php
   echo ' ';
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is in the following if statement

```
if (result == '') {
    // all your code is here
}
```

and you're returning

```
echo ' ';
```

so the code never runs as it's not an empty string, it's a space, remove the if statement

and then there's

```
var result = result;
```

remove that line, it makes no sense!

Comment: sorry i made the dummy return from php 
i do return a blank string based on some conditions in the original php.

Comment: @ashwinbhy - Then what are you expecting when you append an empty string ?

Comment: I am extremely sorry . its a logical error.  thanks !!